# Sql count query with no data

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, inner-join

So what I'm looking for is the 8 ships with more orders, the thing is if there are only 3 ships with orders, the other 5 ships won't show up. 
I would like to have the other ships with 0 orders to show up and ordered by their amount of orders. Is it possible?

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName
LIMIT 8
ORDER BY NumberofOrders DESC;
```

Comment: Invert your tables in the JOIN `FROM Shippers LEFT JOIN ORDERS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders 
FROM 
 Shippers
  LEFT JOIN Orders 
   ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName
LIMIT 8
ORDER BY NumberofOrders DESC;
```